# Accesing Opera GX Corner from a different browser

Tags: browser, web, opera

Does anyone have an idea how to access Opera GX's, GX Corner from a different browser?

In Opera it's pinned as a tab, or accessed through http://gx-corner.opera.com however through the address, it doesn't open with a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

it has a script forbidding to open in any other browser. In fact it calls for native Opera functions. I would like to access in another browser.